# How to change element class on select option using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want change my `class="value"` on select option using jQuery

Example

```
<select name="color_scheme" id="color_scheme">
  <option selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option>Black</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
  <option>Brown</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Gray</option>
  <option>Lime</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>

<span class="Default"></span>
```

If we select Black span class will be

```
<span class="Black"></span>
```

Let me know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I achieved this by storing the default class, and removing that class whenever the select changes.

```
var selectedScheme = 'Default';

$('#color_scheme').change(function(){
    $('span').removeClass(selectedScheme).addClass($(this).val());
    selectedScheme = $(this).val();
});
```

A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/9PeAc/1/

Answer (score 2):

use the `change` event to determine when the user selected another option. To remove all current classes, call `removeClass()` with no arguments. Finally add the new class, which can be accessed by this.value.

```
$('#color_scheme').change(function(e) {
    $('span').removeClass().addClass(this.value);
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/100/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('p').removeClass('myClass noClass').addClass('yourClass');
```